# Local IIS Website Errors

Tags: asp.net

I am using Visual studio web developer 4.0, in which I am creating a locally ISS hosted website.

My problem is while I am opening the website from visual studio I am getting errors such as:

```
ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered on the webserver. You need to manually configure your web server for asp.net 4.0 in order for your site to run correctly...
```

When I am trying to serve a debug website I am getting the error:

```
Unable to start debugging on the server. Could not start asp.net debugging. More information my available by starting the project without debugging.
```

Then I navigated to my startup page without debugging and then the error in browser is

```
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

I have tried registering asp.net with aspnet_regiis -1. I'm using windows 8.

Comment: Did you really use -1 or actually -i?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Manually configure web server for asp.net 4.0
2. Reinstall .NET framework

Number two is recommended.